# Is the ring $R[[x]][\frac{1}{x}]$ Noetherian if $R$ is Noetherian?

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

Let $R$ be a Noetherian ring.

Then its extended polynomial ring $R[x]$ and power series ring $R[[x]]$ both are Noetherian as well.

> Is the ring $R[[x]][\frac{1}{x}]$ Noetherian ?

---

I know if $R$ is Noethetian ring with zero nilradical and if $S$ is the set of regular elements of $R$ (i.e., $S=\{r \in R: rs=0 \Rightarrow s=0\}$), then the ring $S^{-1}R$ is also Noetherian.

So if $R$ is in addition an integral (e.g., $R=\mathbb Z_p=$ ring $p$-adic integers), then $R[[x]][x^{-1}]$ is also Noetherian.

Am I correct ?

Comment: A localization of a noetherian commutatuve ring is noetherian

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez, thanks. Why is $R[[x]][x^{-1}]$ a localization of $R$ ? With respect to which ideal of $R[[x]]$ ?

Comment: It is a localization of R[[x]], not with respect to an ideal but with respect to the multiplicative set of the powers of x.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez, thank you very much

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can think of $R[[x]][x^{-1}]$ as the polynomial ring $R[[x]][y]$ modulo the ideal generated by $xy - 1$ (so that $y = x^{-1}$). Since quotients of Noetherian rings are Noetherian, $R[[x]][x^{-1}]$ is Noetherian.